# android camera preview flip horizontal

Tags: android, camera, android-animation, preview

I'd like to flip the left and right, camera preview

[image]

Like the photo

What can I do?

I am currently using surfaceview

thanks

Comment: use canvas scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use canvas scale

```
canvas.scale((flipHorizontal ? -1 : 1), (flipVertical ? 1 : -1));
```

Comment: params.setPreviewSize(previewW,previewH);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
mCamera.startPreview();         

I use it this way
Can you tell me a little more detail?

Comment: I tried `override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) { canvas?.scale(-1f, 1f)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
}` but it didn't change anything